# Use multiple threads to sell tickets but why there is no error

Tags: java, multithreading

I use multiple threads to simulate ticket sales, but why doesn’t there appear to be multiple threads selling the same ticket?

This is my code:

```java
public class SellTicket {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Ticket ticket = new Ticket();

        new Thread(()->{
            for (int i=0; i< 50; i++) {
                ticket.sell();
            }
        }, "A").start();
        new Thread(()->{
            for (int i=0; i< 50; i++) {
                ticket.sell();
            }
        }, "B").start();
        new Thread(()->{
            for (int i=0; i< 50; i++) {
                ticket.sell();
            }
        }, "C").start();
    }
}

class Ticket {
    private int number = 50;

    public void sell() {
        if (number > 0)
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " selled " + number-- + ", remain " + number);
    }
}
```

And the result is like this:
A selled 50, remain 49
A selled 49, remain 48
A selled 48, remain 47
A selled 47, remain 46
A selled 46, remain 45
...
B selled 35, remain 34
A selled 34, remain 33
B selled 33, remain 32
A selled 32, remain 31
B selled 31, remain 30
A selled 30, remain 29
B selled 29, remain 28
A selled 28, remain 27
B selled 27, remain 26
...
B selled 6, remain 5
B selled 5, remain 4
B selled 4, remain 3
B selled 3, remain 2
B selled 2, remain 1
B selled 1, remain 0

Comment: Well, I *think* that thread A is finished before B even starts, because there is very few work to do. Try to use `50_000_000` instead of `50`.

Comment: I think no, there is something like this in the output:
B selled 35, remain 34  
A selled 34, remain 33  
B selled 33, remain 32  
A selled 32, remain 31  
B selled 31, remain 30  
A selled 30, remain 29  
B selled 29, remain 28    
A selled 28, remain 27  
B selled 27, remain 26

Comment: The field `number` is not `volatile` and not `synchronized` across threads. It's a miracle that thread B sees the right value of `number` while thread A is still modifying it!

Comment: Well, *then* I think that printing to sysout takes much time compared to decrementing `number`, so the chance that two threads interleave is pretty small (since writing to sysout is subject to synchronisation). Try to use many threads.

Comment: I am confused about this. I have executed it many times, but every time the execution result looks correct, I don’t know why he didn’t make a mistake.

Comment: OHHH，You are right! When I use 5 threads and sleep for 10ms in the minus operation, an error occurs successfully. Thank you so much

Comment: By the way, I cannot reproduce your exact same code, as in my case all numbers are over the place (50, 49, 46, 45, 44, 43, 48, 47, 42, 41...)

Comment: Yes, it’s random, sometimes in order and sometimes out of order on my computer

Comment: Just out of curiosity: it seems you're looking for "a successful error" (meaning the same ticket sold twice). Is it just for demonstration purposes? I mean, do you know that you're not synchronizing the field number of the ticket and that you will always have random concurrency failures because of that?

Comment: Yes, I am learning this part of the content. When I wrote this demo, I thought it should have an error, but there was no error at the time, so I felt strange. But now I know the reason, thank you

Comment: Races are never guaranteed! You should not count on that. There are ways to make them more likely, but just because you had none in all your runs doesn’t mean there is no race

Comment: 'number--' is not a single step operation. It's number = number - 1. Use AtomicInteger instead of int or synchronize access to sell method.

Comment: Point of style: A thing that is called `Ticket` in your program should correspond closely to the every-day meaning of "ticket." (I.e., a unique token that entitles a single person to attend an event, ride a ride, etc.) I would rename your `Ticket` class to be `TicketSeller` (it has a `sell()` method...) Or maybe `TicketSource`, or if you want to be cute, `TicketMaster`.

Comment: Point of style II: Your code in `main()` that starts three threads is crying out to be made into a `for` loop.

Comment: As a side note the word is *sold* not “selled”.